# Download Button option in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project which takes some files as input and then gives an output result file to the user. The output file is generated in the backend and takes significant time. I want to create a system where the download button appears only after the file has been generated. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks. :)

Comment: Please provide more details of use case where you want to use this, like if the inputs are fixed or can change. If the output file is getting generated with fixed input. You can consider writing a batch job to create such files, so user has to simply download the already generated files.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide us a few idea or solutions you tried so far, so we can direct you towards the best solution. Currently your question is very broad in terms of potential answers.
The best is to provide us with some ideas you tried so far.

Comment: you can use <meta> to refresh page periodically and server will send old HTML when file is not ready or new HTML with button when file is ready. Or use JavaScript code which will use `AJAX` to send periodically request and check if file is ready - and it will display button when file is ready.